# reset this jquery countdown plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I use this plugin: [jQuery Countdown](https://github.com/kemar/jquery.countdown) in ASP.NET page.

my code is:

.cs file:

```
DateTime time1 = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2).ToString()

Label1.Text = time1.ToString();
```

.aspx file:

```
<script src="JQueryCountDown/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="JQueryCountDown/countdown.demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="JQueryCountDown/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".ctdwn").countDown({});
    });
</script>
...
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" CssClass="ctdwn"></asp:Label>
```

It works properly.

Now I want during that 2 minutes, reset the countdown and start from 2 minutes again(with javascript). But I do not know how to do it. For example this code does not work and disables the countdown:

```
        resetTime = function (dt) {
            $('#Label1').text(dt);
            $(".ctdwn").countDown({});
        };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want is in [the docs](https://github.com/kemar/jquery.countdown#events), here is an example you might find useful:

```
window.jQuery(function ($) {
  function startCountDown() {
    $('.ctdwn').countDown({}).on('time.elapsed', startCountDown);
  }
  startCountDown();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but  it start again after `time.elapsed`. I want to reset it during that 2 minutes. For example in 00:01:39

Comment: Ah ok, sorry then, I didn't get that from your question.

Comment: I gave a brief look at the code, here is where it is calling the setTimeout (https://github.com/kemar/jquery.countdown/blob/master/jquery.countdown.js#L420), it is not storing the return value so I believe there is no easy way to do what you're trying to... unless you monkey patch the lib.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I don't think that this is so difficult.

Comment: Can you tell me how to pause the countdown?

Comment: I was forced to put it aside and use this: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html. ‌Because I do not have enough time to fork it and add my needed capabilities to it.